# Communication between two apps

Tags: flutter, dart, communication

At the moment I am planning on using flutter and dart to create some apps to run on windows/linux/web. Both apps will be running on the same pc.

I want to create two different apps. One will be the ForegroundApp containing a UI. The other will be a BackgroundApp which will be a background service without UI.
I want to be able to communicate between these two apps by passing different type of data like maps, strings and integers.

Optionally, I would like to run the ForegroundApp on a second pc and connect trhough a local network to the BackgroundApp on the first pc. Thus the BackgroundApp must be able to connect to the ForegroundApp multiple times.

I have no idea what to look into on how to program this. Can anyone point me into the best possible direction? This must be without the use of internet or databases.

I tried googling on how to do this, the only thing I found is a suggestion on using http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been investigating a very similar architecture lately and am leaning toward using gRPC (https://pub.dev/packages/grpc) to handle the communication between the two. So far, I'm really happy with the implementation and it can work between two apps on the same PC or between two PCs as well. Might be worth checking out.

Comment: If the two apps are running on the same Android device, how can the grpc client find the grpc host?

Comment: I dont know about Android. I am now using grpc with Flutter and Dart in windows. In one of the apps I have a grpc client running on local host or ip 127.0.0.1. And in the server app I have a grpc server also running on local host or ip 127.0.0.1. And it works perfectly.